# Probability of missing at least 1 test

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The probability that a friend will give chocolate to his on any day is 1/10. A girl is absent twice. What should be the probability that she misses having at least 1 chocolate ?

I am getting totally confused with this type of question. Should I solve this by making a tree with two branches starting ? Or should I consider two days in which the teacher took the test or the two days in which the student was absent ? Am I missing something ? Also, in what category of probability distribution would this question fall ? Can someone please help me out ? Thanks.

Comment: If you engage 'at least' in questions about probability than try to find the probability of the negation of the statement. What is the probability that the student doesn't miss a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider only the two days in which he was absent. so you need to consider three cases :
1. A(test given), B(test not given)
2. A(test not given), B(test given)
3. A(test given), B(test given)

where A and B denote the days on which the student was absent.

So, Probability required = (1/5).(4/5) + (4/5).(1/5) + (1/5).(1/5) = 9/25.

OR

Probability = 1 - Probability(test was not given on both the days) = 1-(4/5).(4/5) = 9/25.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The complement (that he does not miss any test) might be simpler for this question. For him not to miss any test, we need there not to have a test on the two days he is present. That probability is $(\frac{4}{5})^2$. We need not consider other days in this case.